# Access hard drive for VM that won't boot

Tags: google-compute-engine

The hard drive on my VM filled up (it was under a SSH login attack I believe) and now the VM won't boot.

How can I access the boot hard drive so I can clear out space and get it booting again?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#pdboot is helpful but doesn't explain how to detach a boot drive. If you follow their instructions, the gcloud command says it can't attach the boot disk as it's already being used in read-write mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to delete the instance without deleting the boot disk, attach the disk on a temporary instance and then mount it there. The instructions to do this can found here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#ssherrors (Mount your disk on a temporary instance)

You'll then be able to access the disk through the /mnt/myinstance directory, and delete the files. Once the disk is no longer full, you can detach the disk from the temporary instance, and then use it to recreate your original instance.