# Google cloud cant login as root in emergency mode

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have an unwell Google Cloud compute Linux server that cant boot due to a bad entry in the fstab. I have serial console via the google cloud interface. I am at the "Give root password for maintenance or type Control-D to continue" prompt.

Google cloud does not give you a root password when the instance is created. It relies on regular user accounts who then can use sudo to get root. I do not have a root password for this instance.

I have searched but cannot find a way to get root console access with no root password.

Please note, this is Google Cloud compute. I don't think I can interrupt the boot process and edit the boot params like I would on a regular Linux instance.

Answer (score 2):

Fixing an unbootable OS is pretty much the same on every virtualization tool. 
Below is a somewhat more detailed instruction to a question answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037037/access-hard-drive-for-vm-that-wont-boot).

1. Edit the problematic instance and uncheck "Delete boot disk when deleting instance".
2. Delete the instance.
3. Create a temporary instance and add your original disk as an attached disk.
4. SSH into the new instance, create a temporary folder and mount the attached drive.
5. Edit any file you need fixing, in your case `fstab` than unmount disk.
6. Delete the instance you've just created. Your original disk will still exist.
7. Create a new instance this time specify your boot disk as the source.
8. See if it worked.